# Словообразование причастия УЗНАВАЕМЫЙ

Tags: словообразование

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. В школьном учебнике сказано, что страдательные причастия настоящего времени образуются от основы глагола настоящего времени плюс суффикс -ом-(-ем-), если глагол I спряжения. Причастие УЗНАВАЕМЫЙ образовалось от глагола УЗНАЁТ, который в свою очередь образовался от глагола УЗНАВАТЬ. Как объяснить ребёнку, откуда в причастии берётся глагольный суффикс 
-ва-, если он отсутствует в форме начального времени? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

"Узнаваемый"  образуется от глагола  "узнавать":

**у/зна/ва/ть ― у/зна/ва/ем/ый.**

Правило образования причастий от основы настоящего времени "узнаёт" здесь не подходит, так как используется **нестандартная схема** образования формы настоящего времени: узнавать ― узнаёт (а не "узнавает"). А от формы "узнаёт" нельзя образовать причастие по **фонетическим причинам**.

Для сравнения (стандартное словообразование глаголов с суффиксом ВА): умыть/умоет - умывать/умывает/умываемый

**Для справок** (особенности глаголов узнать - узнавать)

Формы настоящего времени для видовой пары глаголов узнАет и узнаёт  (сов. и несов. вид) различаются только ударением. При образовании формы настоящего времени **"узнаёт"** суффикс ВА усекается, что является **особенностью** этого глагола.

Comment: Спасибо. Я нашла ответ. Существует устаревшая форма глагола - ЗНАВАТЬ. Тогда всё встаёт на свои места.

Comment: Мне не очень понятен найденный Вами ответ. Знавать - это глагол несов. вида со значением многократности действия, стиль разговорный, но слово не устаревшее, например: "При всем при том, что времена иные знавать случалось Шевелеву"(1991-1995)] . Но главное: причастие "узнаваемый" НЕ ИМЕЕТ ОТНОШЕНИЯ к глаголу "знавать", оно образуется от глагола "узнавать".